# Uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::OptionsDid you mean? Selenium::WebDriver::Options (NameError)

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

Recently I went through the chrome headless browser selenium automation. I use Selenium-cucumber with ruby.Now I wanted to run my whole project in chrome headless mode using Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.

I updated selenium-webdriver, chrome driver and my chrome version is 61.0.3163.100

In order to get to know its working, I created test.rb with below code:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

#configure the driver to run in headless mode
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
puts driver.title    
driver.quit
```

I was able to get the response as below:

```
>>ruby test.rb
[1012/112029.980:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(786)]
DevTools listening on 127.0.0.1:12703

 Stack Overflow - Where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers
```

Now as I got the response correctly I want to configure the driver to run my project in headless mode.

so I edited the env.rb file of the support folder:

Imported require 'selenium-webdriver' and edited the below part where we create driver instance:

```
else # else create driver instance for desktop browser
  begin
options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com/')
puts driver.title
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e.message
    Process.exit(0)
  end
end
```

I ran the command >>cucumber BROWSER=chrome

```
uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options
Did you mean?  Selenium::WebDriver::Options
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and How can I run my whole selenium-cucumber project in headless mode?

Comment: I hope you have the latest selenium gems?

Comment: Yes Tarun, I have latest selenium gems and as I mentioned I am able to get the output adding the code in via ruby file while I am trying to add that in the env.rb of selenium-cucumber project gives the error.